# How to implement autocomplete input field in Angular app using Bootstrap 4 without JQuery

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to implement an autocomplete input field in an Angular application using Bootstrap 4. This is the desired result:

[image]

Based in some array with countries I need to match the text in the input field with the possible valid countries.

Comment: And what did you try already ?

Comment: I tried to use a template variable to use as parameter in the click event callback, but didn't work.

Comment: I was implicitly telling you to provide the code you already tried, preferably in a stackblitz.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eejygp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made you a **[simple StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ueam1y?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**.

I didn't put any css into it, I will let you handle that.